# How can I confirm that I have table indexes disabled?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have been executing this command to disable indexes in tables. How can I have for sure that indexes are disabled?

I'm using this do disable:

```
ALTER table DISABLE KEYS
```

How can I test if the indexes are really disabled?

Comment: keep in mind that it will disable only non-unique indexes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-index.html

```
SHOW INDEX FROM tablename;
```

30

Comment: In my MySQL version (5.6) only works with FROM: `SHOW INDEX FROM tablename`. I think it is mandatory in all versions [link]http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-index.html

Answer (score 3):

ALTER TABLE 'table-name' ENABLE KEYS;   -- It will  enable keys for TABLE
ALTER TABLE 'table-name' DISABLE KEYS;   -- It will  disable keys for TABLE

Run following Query:

select  * from  information_schema.statistics 
where  TABLE_SCHEMA='db_name' and TABLE_NAME='table-name';

-It gives the list of indexes on selected Database with table_name,index_name,index_type,comment etc.

-Check 'Comment' column  it  will  show you  status enable/disable for  keys.

Note: FOR enable status 'Comment' column  value is blank,that  means  key  is  enabled.

DISABLE/ENABLE index  useful at the  time of  bulk insert  to  faster  execution of insert statements.